# Replace a string using in Java

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where there is a particular string in a line to be replaced

Below is my sample program.

```
public class MyFirstJavaProgram {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        String x="<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"abc.css\" />";
        System.out.println(x);

    }
}
```

In the above program I want to replace `abc.css` with `xyz.css`. I'm aware of general String replacement function like `String.replace(oldString, newString)`, But here the problem is that `abc.css` changes from file to file. I want to replace `anything.css` with `xyz.css`.

Here is a working Example [Fiddle](https://ideone.com/xw8e0r)

please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks

Comment: Don't bind your code to a hard coded string then... use regex

Comment: Hi @Xoce웃Пepeúpa, Any suggestion on how do i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 x=x.replaceAll("(.*)\"(.*)\\.css", "$1\"xyz\\.css");
```

Comment: This is not working as Expected. The output that I get is `<link rel="stylesheet" type="textxyz.css" href="abcxyz.css" />` instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" type="textxyz.css" href="xyz.css" />`

Comment: Here is a live demo https://ideone.com/xw8e0r

Comment: Sorry, failed with the escape characters. I edit the answer and give you a live demo. I've taken in consideration that you must have it inside quotes ("...") https://ideone.com/WfWtHr

Comment: Thanks mate. This worked :)